# Expected generations until first mutation (aka, trials to first success with non-constant p)

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, expectation, means

Imagine a bacterial population growing exponentially (doubling its size at each generation). The population starts at $t=0$ with $x_0=1$ cells, so $x_t=2^t$. Each generation cells copy themselves, having a probability $p$ per copy of generating a mutation. The question is: how many generations will it take on average to observe the first mutation?

Let's $Y$ be the number of generations to the first mutation, we can compute the expectation as:

$$ E(Y)=1·p+2·(1-p)(1-(1-p)^{2})+3·(1-p)^{3}(1-(1-p)^{4}) +... $$

$$ E(Y)=\sum_{t=1}^{k} t (1-p)^{2^{t-1}-1}(1-(1-p)^{2^{t-1}})$$

which looks like the expectation for the geometric distribution but with a exponentially increasing probability that at some generation $k=log_2(1/p)$ reaches unity.

I'd like to come up with a formula for this expectation, but I don't know even where to start (the common ratio trick doesn't seem possible). I wonder if this kind of series has a specific name that I can look up for (a related question has been asked here: [Geometric distribution with unequal probabilities for trials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435746/geometric-distribution-with-unequal-probabilities-for-trials))

Comment: You seem to think that $P(Y=1)=p$, $P(Y=2)=2p(1-p)$, $P(Y=3)=4p(1-p)(1-2p)$, and so on. This is obviously wrong.

Comment: Indeed $\mathsf P(Y=1)=1-(1-p)^2$ because that is the probability that at least one of the two cells born into generation 1 mutates.  $\mathsf P(Y=2) = (1-(1-p)^4)(1-p)^2$ via being the probability that neither generation 1 mutates and at least one of the four in generation two does.  And so on.  $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y=k) ~=~& (1-(1-p)^{2^k})\prod_{j=1}^{k-1}(1-p)^{2^j} \\ =~& (1-(1-p)^{2^k})~(1-p)^{\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}2^j} \\ =~& (1-(1-p)^{2^k})~(1-p)^{2^k-2} \\ =~& (1-p)^{2^k-2}-(1-p)^{2^{k+1}-2}\end{align}$$...and such.

Comment: Sure, the $P(Y=k)$ I used are wrong. Thank you both for pointing that out. However, the process I'm interested into is not exactly as Graham Kemp understood (flipping $2^t$ coins until you get at least 1 head). I should have noted that bacteria grow by making one copy of themselves per generation, so there are as many 'coin tosses' as cells in the population (that is, at $t=1$ only one coin has been flipped). We can write:

$$P(Y=1)=p$$
$$P(Y=2)=(1-p)(1-(1-p)(1-p))$$
$$P(Y=3)=(1-p)(1-p)(1-p)(1-(1-p)(1-p)(1-p)(1-p))$$
$$P(Y=k)=(1-p)^{2^{k-1}-1}(1-(1-p)^{2^{k-1}})$$